# Ruby Subclass Error on String array

Tags: ruby

Im Sure this is something wrong with my classes but here it is:

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :transaction_date, :amount, :other_info, :type, :purchase
end

require 'csv'
require_relative '../../app/models/transaction'
csv_text = File.read('monthly_csvs/pcbanking.csv')
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => false)
csv.each do |row|
  puts row[3].to_s
  Transaction.create!(transaction_date: row[0], amount: row[1], other_info: row[2], type: row[3], purchase: row[4])
end
```

ERROR:

```
POS Purchase
rake aborted!
Invalid single-table inheritance type: POS Purchase is not a subclass of Transaction
```

Pos Purchase is the row[3] element and is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails (or more specifically ActiveRecord) uses the `type` column by default in a model to implement [Single Table Inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Single+table+inheritance) (STI). This is a technique to implement multiple inherited models which are saved in the same database table.

As you use the `type` column in your model, Rails expects it to be used for STI. You could now either rename your `type` column to something else or instruct Rails to use another column as the STI type column by using this in your model class (in this example to the `sti_type` column):

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.inheritance_column = :sti_type
end
```